# How to check if a pseudo-element ::after exists or not using Selenium Python

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, pseudo-element

I need to identify if the ::after pseudo element exist or not.
When it exist:

```
<div class="vcp-bigplay" xpath="1"></div>
  ::after
</div>
```

When it does not exist:

```
<div class="vcp-bigplay" xpath="1"></div>
```

I tried

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.vcp-bigplay>div')
```

and

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.vcp-bigplay::after')
```

and

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.vcp-bigplay:after')
```

None of them works. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript executor to retrieve the content value and then check if that exists or not.

Something like this

```
script = "return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.vcp-bigplay'),'::after').getPropertyValue('content')";
 
            element = driver.execute_script(script);
            if (len(element)==0):
                 print('not there')
            else:
                 print('there')
```

You can read in detail [here](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/handling-pseudo-elements-in-css-with-selenium/).

Comment: It prints 'there' all the time, whether ::after exists or not